# translatable content: how to set default original language

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n

I've a D9 site, configured with two languages: Italian (default) and English.

Some content types of the site are translable, the configuration under `admin/config/regional/content-language` for them is as the following:

[image]

The configuration of `admin/config/regional/language/detection` is the following:

[image]

#### How it is now

When the user adds new content, if the url has `en` the content is created as English, and translatable in Italian.

When the url has `it`, the content is created in Italian and translatable in English.

#### How I want it to have

I'd like for coherence and to possibly avoid unforeseen problems that **all** the translatable content is created in Italian and translatable in English, independently of current URL\User settings.

---

The configuration under `/admin/structure/types/manage/article` is similar to the one under content-language:

[image]

How can I achieve that? I've tried to tamper with "Content language detection" but found no working way to set up it (and I've no idea at all if the setting to alter to achieve this result)

Comment: Can't it be set at https://example.com/admin/structure/types/manage/article at the bottom under language settings?

Comment: @leymannx: I've updated the answer, the default language there was already in "italian". Actually I'm pretty positive the settings under a specific content type are the same of the "general list" under 'admin/config/regional/content-language'.

Comment: Seems you already have the right settings for it. Is this not working? Like when you show the language selector just for testing and create a new article, it isn't in Italian independent from the current interface language? Or is it that you want to switch the source language for already existing article?

Comment: @leymannx: it is *not* working. I'll repeat the case: the editor is in "English" - he has likely set up the current language via the switcher available in the frond-end theme. Then, he adds a new 'article' (the theme is admin). That article will have 'EN' as default language and 'IT' as translation - so the settings does not work. I've realized this problem\bug after users started to create nodes. My priority is to fix this problem for new nodes, I think the site can work with the existing having this problem - although as you're asking, I'd like to swap the language for those too if possible.

Comment: As a quickfix you should simply expose the language selector and move it to top of the form. I can't replicate what you describe in a fresh Drupal installation. Interface language is respected. Must be something else in your setup that's interferring.

Comment: @leymannx thank you for your time. The suggestion that a fresh drupal installation had not this problem lead me to test everything custom we added on the site. In the end I could identify the cause in a custom implementation a collegue has done. Without that part the site works well, so now I have a clear point where to work.

Comment: Nice! Glad I could help you move forward. 